# How can I record incoming calls on Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I have a website that uses Twilio to allow people to use our temporary numbers to receive SMS messages received during verification processes etc. It is becomming more common that companies are switching to audio verification instead so I want to start recording all calls received and displaying them in the existing HTML table using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

Here is the existing code:

```
                      <tbody>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('twilio/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = ""; 
$token = ""; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    'To' => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] // this is the number
)); 

foreach ($messages as $message) { 
    echo "<tr><td>" . $message->from . "</td><td>" . $message->date_sent . "</td><td>" . $message->body . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

How can I build in to that the recorded calls received? I want to keep it in date/time order within the eixsting SMS messages, if that makes sense.

Comment: Show us what you did to achieve this and what's not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely record calls with Twilio.

When you create a call, you just need to [include the parameter `Record=true` in the REST API request to create a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). Then, if you include a [`statusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) that points to a URL on your server, then you will receive a webhook to that URL when the call is complete that includes a link to the recording.

You can also [fetch the latest recordings from the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording). You can get recordings in wav or mp3 format, which you can then use in the HTML `<audio>` element.

I'm not sure how you have set up your date ordered SMS table, but hopefully this helps. Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of SMS I don't store any on the server, we solely use the API so I would prefer to do it all on Twilio's end and continue using the API for audio also. I have put the existing table that shows the SMS received, I want to somehow 'slot' the recordings in to that to, in date/time order. Any idea on the best way to handle that?

Comment: So, you can make an API request that returns calls by the number, much like you do with messages, however you'd then need to make an API request for each call in that list in order to get the recording details and the URL of the audio file. With more than a few calls in the list that is likely to get impractical. I'd probably recommend storing this data yourself somehow.

Comment: Ok. How do I set it to record all incoming calls? I haven't got it set to notify my server and I'd rather not rely on that anyway.

Comment: The various ways of recording calls can be found here: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-record-a-phone-call-with-twilio

Comment: Seems to me it's not written anywhere how to "record an incoming phonecall", as stated in the question

Comment: For incoming calls, you want to use the [`<Record>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) verb. Sorry I didn't get that you meant incoming the first time.